# Failed to install rook on k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I am trying to create a rook cluster inside k8s cluster.

Set up - 1 master node, 1 worker node

These are the steps I have followed

```
Master node: 
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/32a765fd19ba45b387fdc5e3812c41fff47cfd55/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubeadm token create --print-join-command

Worker node: 
kubeadm join {master_ip_address}:6443 --token {token} --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash {hash} --apiserver-advertise-address={worker_private_ip}

Master node - Install rook - (reference - https://rook.github.io/docs/rook/master/ceph-quickstart.html):
kubectl create -f ceph/common.yaml
kubectl create -f ceph/operator.yaml
kubectl create -f ceph/cluster-test.yaml
```

Error while creating rook-ceph-operator pod:

```
(combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = 
Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "4a901f12e5af5340f2cc48a976e10e5c310c01a05a4a47371f766a1a166c304f" 
network for pod "rook-ceph-operator-fdfbcc5c5-jccc9": networkPlugin cni failed to 
set up pod "rook-ceph-operator-fdfbcc5c5-jccc9_rook-ceph" network: failed to set bridge addr: 
"cni0" already has an IP address different from 10.244.1.1/24
```

[image]

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Hello nidhi which cni network you are using ? is it canico or flannel ?

Comment: did you tried to change `--pod-network-cidr` when you reinitialize Kubernetes via kubeadm init ?

Comment: @HarshManvar flannel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue start if you did `kubeadm reset` and after that `kubeadm init` reinitialize Kubernetes.

```
kubeadm reset
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*
rm -rf /etc/cni/
ifconfig cni0 down
ifconfig flannel.1 down
ifconfig docker0 down
```

After this start docker and kubelet and kubeadm again.

**Work around**

You can also try this way as simple easy solution

```
ip link delete cni0
ip link delete flannel.1
```

that depends on which network you are using inside k8s.

Comment: I have already tried it. It didn't work. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39557#issuecomment-271944481

Comment: Ok. I will try it again. Thanks.

Comment: Along with what you have mentioned i had to do `iptables --flush`,
`iptables -tnat --flush` these two steps as well. It worked after that.

Comment: @NidhiAgarwal that's great glad to here. Zomato using k8s ? :).

Comment: I am doing it out of interest. Not for zomato. :)

Comment: oh that's so great...glad to hear that.